Back-propagation through embedding layer
I was trying to understand how back-propogation works through embedding layer. After I wrote the equation, it seems like the gradient with respect to the weight of embedding layer is always 1.
$$
\underset{d \times 1}{\vec{e}} = \underset{d\times v}{W} \space \space \underset{v\times 1}{\vec{x}} 
$$
$$
\text{W = Embedding matrix}
\\
\vec{x} = \text{One hot encoded vector}
\\
\vec{e} = \text{Embedding vector}
$$
Each component $e_i$ can be written in the form of
$$
e_{i} = \sum_{j=0}^{j = (v-1)}{w_{ij}a_{j}}   \quad\quad \space 0 < i < d
\\
\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial w_{ij}} = ?
$$
Is this true $\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial w_{ij}} = a_j = 1 $  ??
